# Function I can use to stop negative numbers and #value in networkdays function

Tags: excel-formula, worksheet-function

I have attempted to stop negative numbers and #value from appearing in a networkdays function. I want to calculate the networkdays but not count the first day. I tried researching the possible functions that would solve this and came up with this:

`=IFERROR(IF(NETWORKDAYS(E9,F9,MenuData!G3:G22)<0,"",NETWORKDAYS(E9,F9,MenuData!G3:G22)-1),0)`

It does show a blank cell on the rows with negative numbers and the negative numbers are because there is only a value in cell E or F. But on rows where there are two dates, it makes the cell 0.

Comment: I'm sure that if you included sample data, you'll get an answer.

Comment: I solved it. Here's what I did in case someone else has the same problem I did (I am still learning): ```=IFERROR(IF(AH7="","0", IF(NETWORKDAYS(C7,AH7,MenuData!$G$3:$G$22)<0, "0", (NETWORKDAYS(C7,AH7,MenuData!G3:G22)-1))),0)```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Here's what I did in case someone else has the same problem I had (I am still learning):

`=IFERROR(IF(AH7="",0, IF(NETWORKDAYS(C7,AH7,MenuData!$G$3:$G$22)<0, 0, (NETWORKDAYS(C7,AH7,MenuData!$G$3:$G$22)-1))),0)`

This avoids negative numbers due to having blank cells in the spreadsheet and stops errors (#VALUE) in case there are N/A where the dates should be.